# More on equals and hashCode

Tags: java, hashcode

I understand the contract between the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. If `equals` is overridden, `hashCode` should also be. Can I override the `hashCode` method to always return the same value, say the int 23? Can I override the `hashCode` method to return a random number each time it is called?

Comment: **Can** you? Sure. But what would happen if you did?

Comment: If you ask such a question, you sure need to reread the contract. hashcode and equals are two faces of the same coin. Neither makes full sense without the other. I could give you a 500 line write up about it but to learn better you need to figure it out yourself.

Comment: When I override the hashCode to return a constant or a random int the compiler didn't panic or complain. Which made me wonder, if this is valid, why is it not advised. I missed the bigger picture of the HashSet, HashMap.. which rely on Hashing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't override `hashCode` to return a random value. It should always return the same value for the same instance.

This is clearly stated in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) :

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified.

You shouldn't return a constant value, since it would make a very poor `hashCode` when used in classes such as `HashMap` and `HashSet`.

This is also mentioned in the Javadoc :

> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, **the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.**

Comment: Additionally to make things easier there is a very nice Utility function: Objects.hash(objects....);   returns an int that you can return as a hashcode. basically does all the dirty work for you.

Comment: another point to remember the hash code should be based off invariant items that identify the object instance. you don't want codes that will change as folks set state in the object.